# Suggested edits : changes in titles

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, titles

When reviewing suggested Edit, there is a side by side view before/after of the post.

Could it possible to have the same feature for changes in the titles? It can be quite difficult to validate an Edit in some case without this features, e.g.
[image]

Comment: Some related posts on [meta.se]: [Please show changed titles separately in edit diffs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135710), [Please keep title edits display consistent with content edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112724). One of the answers there mentions a userscript for this, it is a part of [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091). (I haven't tested whether/how it works.)

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak, I looked at related posts on this Meta Math site but forgot to check the Meta SE site.